# CollectionView horizontally scroll item independent each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am a junior at iOS developing using Objective-C. I have a question about collection views. I have an app which give information about institutions like hotels, restaruants, shops … (Count of institution maybe 50). And I want to show this by using a collection view. Is it possible to scroll horizontally the first section items in my collection view independently each other section's items?

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, YES it is possible

Comment: Yes by creating different custom cells for each institutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You can have different sections in a `UICollectionView` with different items for each section provided.

You can for example have a `section` for your Hotels, and every hotel in that specific section as a list of `items`. And the next section for Shops etc.

And each section and its items can be completely unique and independent.

You do this by checking `NSIndexPath` of the cell and provide the correct data to the `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.item` of your choise in [cellForItemAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618088-cellforitematindexpath) methods.